# Import-CSV DateTime issue

Tags: powershell, csv, datetime

I'm having difficulties converting  the **'Ship Date'** Column to `datetime` objects. What am I doing wrong?

```
"Ticket","Ship Date","ID","Tracking"
"1a","04/04/2020","123123","1ZE77A119042853562"
"2g","04/04/2020","456456","1ZE77A119042854758"
```

```
$rows = Import-CSV "C:\pathtocsv.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Ticket = $_.'Ticket'
        'Ship Date'       = $_.'Ship Date' -as [datetime]
        ID                = $_.ID
        Tracking          = $_.Tracking
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I have, thank you!

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine, the dates are getting converted to a `datetime` object. Maybe clarify what is your expected result or what makes you think the code is not working.

Comment: As an aside: `$_.'Ship Date' -as [datetime]` returns `$null` if a given input string cannot be parsed as `[datetime]`. If you can assume that all strings can be parsed and/or you want an error to occur for those that cannot, use a _cast_: `[datetime] $_.'Ship Date'`

Comment: Yes,  this is the correct way #smh. Thank you for your assistance @Santiago

Comment: @MattyS `04/04/2020`... Is that `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy` ?  Please, if you type example dates, at least show something that makes that clear